# How to install debug symbols for libc++ on Ubuntu?

Tags: libc++

How to install debug symbols for libc++ on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Right now I'm having to resort to compile everything with -fstandalone-debug.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same thing starting yesterday and today found this wiki link:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

succinctly:

1. add the sources for their debug symbol packages

```sh
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
```

2. import the signing key for said packages

```sh
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

3. update your package list to include the new ones

```sh
sudo apt-get update
```

4. now you can install `*-dbgsym` packages, I found which libc++ package I had installed like so:

```sh
apt list --installed | grep libc++
```

5. I had libc++1-11. I checked that the -dbgsym package existed brutishly like so:

```sh
sudo apt search libc++ | grep -P 'libc\+\+.*dbgsym'
```

6. And of course installed the one I needed:

```sh
sudo apt install libc++1-11-dbgsym
```

I got a hint at the right solution from the final comment in this thread: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24202

Comment: the article also mentions that for older versions of ubuntu replace step 2 with:
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2EDC64DC5AEE1F6B9C621F0C8CAB6595FDFF622`

Comment: I still can't see std::string previews in my debugger :(

Comment: In my case I actually needed libstdc++ not libc++ so you can try the same steps but for libstdc++